# How to fix rotations on bones?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, weight-painting

so I've created this Character and was trying to give him some bones. I add the IK bone to move the legs around. For some reason as soon as it gets to a certain, point the bone starts to rotate giving weird deformations in the Hip. Another thing is that the feet are deformated all the time when I'm in pose or edit mode, I don't know why. How can I remove these deformations?[image][image]

Comment: Forgot to add the blender file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ejtD9z9xt9EQxnLj6GlJ_MXxhl5g06ZN

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the bone's *Pole Angle* (choose -90°). Also, you'll need to move the *Pole Target* bone so that your leg doesn't twist too much when moving.

[image]